# The memory of cgroup rss is much higher than the summary of the memory usage of all processes in the docker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, memory, redis, cgroups

I hava a Redis runing in a container .
Inside the container cgroup rss show using about 1283MB memory.

The kmem memory usage is 30.75MB.

The summary of the memory usage of all processes in the docker container is 883MB.

How can i figure out the  "disappeared memory "(1296-883-30=383MB).The  "disappeared memory" will growing with the time pass.Flinally  the container will be oom killed .

environmet info is

```
redis version:4.0.1

docker version:18.09.9

k8s version:1.13
```

**the memory usage is 1283MB **

```
root@redis-m-s-rbac-0:/opt#cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes 
1346289664  >>>> 1283.921875 MB
```

the kmem memory usage is 30.75MB

```
root@redis-m-s-rbac-0:/opt#cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.kmem.usage_in_bytes 
32194560  >>> 30.703125 MB
```

```
root@redis-m-s-rbac-0:/opt#cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat 
cache 3358720
rss 1359073280 >>>  1296.11328125 MB
rss_huge 515899392
shmem 0
mapped_file 405504
dirty 0
writeback 0
swap 0
pgpgin 11355630
pgpgout 11148885
pgfault 25710366
pgmajfault 0
inactive_anon 0
active_anon 1359245312
inactive_file 2351104
active_file 1966080
unevictable 0
hierarchical_memory_limit 4294967296
hierarchical_memsw_limit 4294967296
total_cache 3358720
total_rss 1359073280
total_rss_huge 515899392
total_shmem 0
total_mapped_file 405504
total_dirty 0
total_writeback 0
total_swap 0
total_pgpgin 11355630
total_pgpgout 11148885
total_pgfault 25710366
total_pgmajfault 0
total_inactive_anon 0
total_active_anon 1359245312
total_inactive_file 2351104
total_active_file 1966080
total_unevictable 0
```

**the summary of the memory usage of all processes in the docker container is 883MB **

```
root@redis-m-s-rbac-0:/opt#ps aux | awk '{sum+=$6} END {print sum / 1024}'
883.609
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279477/disable-transparent-huge-pages-from-kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `usage_in_bytes` does not show exact value of memory and swap usage. The `memory.usage_in_bytes`  show current memory(RSS+Cache) usage.

> **5.5 usage_in_bytes For efficiency, as other kernel components, memory cgroup uses some optimization to avoid unnecessary cacheline
> false sharing. usage_in_bytes is affected by the method and doesn't
> show 'exact' value of memory (and swap) usage, it's a fuzz value for
> efficient access. (Of course, when necessary, it's synchronized.) If
> you want to know more exact memory usage, you should use
> RSS+CACHE(+SWAP) value in memory.stat(see 5.2).**

Reference:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I found the reason why the additional memory i  cannot figure out 。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279477/disable-transparent-huge-pages-from-kubernetes

Comment: @nobb how does the THP impact the additional memory usage ?  causing memory floating?